# How to collect the data from another app before it goes to the UI?

Tags: automation, background-process

I'm using an android app, it receives backend updates and displays on the UI.

How could an automation app, a script, or any solution read the updates received and to make some decisions/start other services before it is sent to UI?

Android at wi-fi with the weather forecast app.
App or service collecting the data stream in the backend.
Uses the data collected in the backend to automate decisions.

thanks.

Comment: Which Android app are you using for receiving weather forecast? It is likely the app is receiving forecast from a third-party server. Apps such as Tasker can manipulate or act on such data if link to third-party is known. You can try Tasker subreddit for your issue if you don't  get your issue solved here.

Comment: It looks like a native Android app, using one API.
The data are displayed into small cards with four pieces of information.
City name on the top (Los Angeles);
Weather forecast (Sun Mon-Fri);
Temperature (XXF);
Conditions (Sun/wind/shower)
How could I access this information through the backend (com.provider.app), activity and automate other services in the real world?

Comment: Still, it is best if you could just link the app here. Anyhow, if I were in this situation I would try to single out the domains/URLs the app is trying to connect to. I would first block all apps (including system apps) from accessing internet but allow this app to access it by using a firewall app, then I'd use a network sniffer to capture the packets sent/received by this app. // There might be simpler ways to achieve all of this.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Firelord.
Unfortunately, I cannot list the app for licensing reasons. It's a paid service.
I tried the Wireshark to capture packages from the mobile, unsuccessful.

Comment: Sorry. Don't know what else to do right now.

Comment: Thanks @Firelord

Answer (score 1):

The data once received by an app is protected by the Android sandboxing system that restricts/protects each app. Hence unless your device is rooted the received data (and the app does not provide a public interface to access the data) is inaccessible to any other app (hence also to any automation app).

The only chance to get some data would be on the transmission level by intercepting the connection between app and server. However nowadays this connections usually is a HTTPS connection which means that the app would no accept the presented server certificate of the man-in-the-middle proxy as apps only allow the default system certificates as root certificates. Here again rooting would be the only option to add a custom certificate to your device to make the weather app accept the custom server certificate.